# $x^{y}=y^{x}$ Intersection Question

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

I'm looking at this problem, $x^{y}=y^{x}$ and the question is to find the point of intersection of the two curves that form  a solution set. I understand how to find the point of intersection using a different method, but I don't understand the following solution.  Why is it when "f(x)" is at a minimum or maximum, we have intersection of the two curves?

http://math.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/pages/solutions_1.pdf

Comment: If you plot $f(x)=x^{1/x}$ and draw horizontal line, intersection points with the graph of $f$ are precisely solutions of this equation. Below maximum, there are two intersection points, at maximum they degenerate to one.

Comment: The solution set to x^y and y^x is a union of the curve y=x, with another curve.  Those two curves intersect at one point (e,e).  What do you mean by there are two intersection points?